# Why does this code not wait before termination?

Tags: c

why does this code terminate imidiately after i run ? i think it should wait 10 second befor terninate ?

```
#include<windows.h>
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    CreateProcess("child.exe", NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
    WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, 10000);
    TerminateProcess(pi.hProcess, 0);
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How long is `child.exe` running for?

Comment: the second parameter to `WaitForSingleObject` is just the timeout. It returns immediately as soon it has the result, success or failure.

Comment: Always check the outcome of the functions you call.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps the `CreateProcess` failed?

If your application depends on the child process being created, you should add an exception or an assert:

```
if (!CreateProcess("child.exe", NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
{
    assert(!"child.exe didn't run");
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: @thanh if child.exe doesn't start, you need to figure out why that happens. Where is that file located? Is it in the same directory as your main application? Can you start that program by itself?

Comment: thanks you because of your help i has solve the problem